# JS Number of occurences in a sequence is a prime number

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, sequence, primes

I have two arrays (X and Y) and I need to create array Z that contains all elements from array X except those, that are present in array Y p times where p is a prime number.
I am trying to write this in JS.
For Example:

Array X:
`[2, 3, 9, 2, 5, 1, 3, 7, 10]`
Array Y:
`[2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 10, 6, 6, 1, 7, 10, 10, 10]`
Array Z:
`[2, 9, 2, 5, 7, 10]`

So far I have this:

```
const arrX = [2, 3, 9, 2, 5, 1, 3, 7, 10]
const arrY = [2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 10, 6, 6, 1, 7, 10, 10, 10]
const arrZ = []
const counts = [];

// count number occurrences in arrY
for (const num of arrY) {
  counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
}

// check if number is prime
const checkPrime = num => {
    for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) if (num % i === 0) return false
    return true
}

console.log(counts[10]);
// returns 4
```

Any hint or help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: does it have to be in any certain order?

Comment: Small note: you can rewrite `counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;` as `counts[num] = ++counts[num] || 1` (taking advantage of the fact that ++undefined yields the falsey value `NaN`, rather than throwing an error).

Comment: @m.said Yes, I want to keep the order.

Comment: @RBarryYoung In ```arrZ``` I need all numbers which are in ```arrX``` except those, that are present in ```arrY``` p times, where p is a prime number. So, ```2``` is present in ```arrY``` one time - ```1``` is not a prime, so I keep both ```2``` from ```arrX``` in ```arrZ```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. `counts` should be an object mapping elements in `arrY` to their number of occurrences. It's easily gotten with `reduce`.

The prime check needs a minor edit, and the last step is to filter `arrX`. The filter predicate is just a prime check on the count for that element.

```js
// produce an object who's keys are elements in the array
// and whose values are the number of times each value appears
const count = arr => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, n) => {
    acc[n] = acc[n] ? acc[n]+1 : 1;
    return acc;
  }, {})
}

// OP prime check is fine, but should handle the 0,1 and negative cases:
const checkPrime = num => {
    for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) if (num % i === 0) return false
    return num > 1;
}

// Now just filter with the tools you built...
const arrX = [2, 3, 9, 2, 5, 1, 3, 7, 10]
const arrY = [2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 10, 6, 6, 1, 7, 10, 10, 10]
const counts =  count(arrY);
const arrZ = arrX.filter(n => checkPrime(counts[n]));
console.log(arrZ)
```

Comment: Ok, so now I have deleted those filtered elements from ```arrX``` and it works perfect. Thank you sooo much!
`const arrSolution = arrX.filter(item => !arrZ.includes(item))
console.log(arrSolution)
// returns [2, 9, 2, 5, 7, 10]`

Comment: Ah, you're going for the inverse?  Answer those that *don't* appear prime times?  It's simpler to just flip the condition on the filter... `arrX.filter(n => !checkPrime(counts[n]));`. See the `!` ?